# XML to Objects in VB

Tags: xml, vb.net, object, serialization, deserialization

What i want to do is take any given .xml file and turn it into a object in VB code. My program will grab a .xml file from a website and change it into a object. Then i will be running query's against these objects created from the .xml files. Then i will be outputting these query's to a data-grid.

Thing is i know how to do all this with one specific .xml file. I just put references to the fields in the .xml file to change it into a object. But when it comes to changing any .xml possible that can be upload by user with many different fields, i am at a lose.

Is there anyway to do this ?

Comment: You can't convert arbitrary XML into arbitrary objects and then do queries on it. What you _can_ do is to store the XML into a SQL Server database as the "XML" data type, then perform XQuery queries on it. The XML column can even have indexes to speed up performance.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: SQL Server seems like overkill here, meh?  XPath against XmlDocument seems like the place to start - move in to SQL Server as requirements/performance demand.

Comment: If XPath queries are sufficient, then I would use LINQ to XML and XPath, or perhaps just LINQ to XML. If XQuery is required, then I don't think SQL Server Express is much overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an XML compiler utilizing the `System.Xml` and `System.Reflection.Emit` namespaces.

But you are still going to face the challenge of querying objects whose structure you don't know about until runtime.

A better option might be to just load up the xml into an `XmlDocument` and run XPath or LINQ queries against them.  XPath most likely, given the Hisenburgian nature of the objects.

```
Dim tDoc as XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
Dim tNodes As XmlNodeList = Nothing

tDoc.Load(file_path)
tNodes = tDoc.SelectNodes("xpath query goes here")
For Each tNode As XmlNode In tNodes
  ' Do something with the Node
Next
```

Comment: Any examples of xpath would be useful, trying to get it going but seems its a it over my head to get it to read any xml file.